# MySQL Contar registros no existentes de una tabla en otra tabla relacionada

Tags: mysql, sql, join

estoy intentando hacer un COUNT de los id de una tabla que no aparecen en otra, en dos tablas relacionadas. Esto es lo que he intentado pero la consulta devuelve 0 filas:

```
SELECT t2.id, IdC,
    COUNT(t2.id)
FROM tabla2 t2
     LEFT JOIN tabla1 t1 ON t1.id = idM
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT idM FROM tabla2 t2
    WHERE t1.id = idM)
GROUP BY IdC
```

Estas son las tablas, es decir, necesitaría contar los registros de la tabla1 que no aparecen en la tabla2 para cada IdC:

```
   tabla1
    id  mName
    1   B
    2   A
    3   M
    4   C
    5   DW
    6   DM
    7   BJ
    8   BC
    9   RF
    10  GC

    tabla2
    id  idM IdC
    1   1   1
    2   5   1
    3   4   1
    4   3   1
    5   2   1
    7   1   2
    8   5   2
    9   4   2
```

El resultado esperado sería algo como esto:

```
id  idC COUNT(t2.id)
1   1   5
2   2   7
```

Es decir, contar los registros que no aparecen la tabla2 para cada idC (6, 7, 8, 9, 10 = 5 resultados para idC 1 y 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 = 7 resultados para idC 2)

Siguiendo con el mismo enunciado, ¿cómo podría llegar a esta solución?

```
    +-----+-----+------+
    | idM | CNT | NCNT |
    +-----+-----+------+
    |   1 |   2 |    0 |
    |   2 |   1 |    1 |
    |   3 |   1 |    1 |
    |   4 |   2 |    0 |
    |   5 |   2 |    0 |
    |   6 |   0 |    2 |
    |   7 |   0 |    2 |
    |   8 |   0 |    2 |
    |   9 |   0 |    2 |
    |  10 |   0 |    2 |
    +-----+-----+------+
```

Es decir contar en la columna CNT los registros existentes para cada idM y en la columna NCNT los registros no existentes para cada idM.

He intentado esta consulta pero en la columna NCNT no consigo agrupar los registros para cada idM.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id AS idM,
    COUNT(t2.id) AS CNT,
    np.cnt AS NCNT,
FROM tabla3 t3
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM tabla3 t3
        JOIN tabla1 t1
        LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.idC = t3.id
        WHERE t2.id IS NULL) np
JOIN tabla1 t1
LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.idC = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

EDITADO:

```
tabla3  
+-----+-----+------+------+
|  id |cName|  CTR |  CTT |
+-----+-----+------+------+
|   1 |  C1 |    A |    X |
|   2 |  C2 |    A |    X |
|   3 |  C3 |    A |    X |
|   4 |  C4 |    B |    X |
|   5 |  C5 |    B |    X |
|   6 |  C6 |    C |    Y |
+-----+-----+------+------+
```

Si la tabla3 tuviera dos columnas más (CTR y CTT) ¿cómo podría contar el número de valores distintos de forma que el resultado quedara por ejemplo así?

```
+-----+-----+------+------+------+
| idM | CNT | NCNT | NCNT | NCNT |
+-----+-----+------+------+------+
|   1 |   6 |    0 |    3 |    2 |
|   2 |   5 |    1 |    2 |    1 |
|   3 |   5 |    1 |    2 |    1 |
|   4 |   4 |    2 |    2 |    1 |
|   5 |   2 |    4 |    2 |    2 |
|   6 |   0 |    6 |    0 |    0 |
|   7 |   0 |    6 |    0 |    0 |
|   8 |   0 |    6 |    0 |    0 |
|   9 |   0 |    6 |    0 |    0 |
|  10 |   0 |    6 |    0 |    0 |
+-----+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Con esos datos que pones de ejemplo, ¿cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: no comprendo, quizás es por el formato del comentario, creo que es mejor que edites tu pregunta e incluyas esa información dentro de la misma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes definida otra tabla que contenga las entidades a las que se refiere `idC`, se puede visualizar una solución fácilmente. Imaginemos que es:

```
tabla3
id cName
1  C1
2  C2
```

El producto cartesiano de `tabla1` y `tabla3` es:

```
SELECT t1.id AS idM, t3.id AS idC
FROM   tabla1 t1
JOIN   tabla3 t3;

+-----+-----+
| idM | idC |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   2 |
|   2 |   1 |
|   2 |   2 |
|   3 |   1 |
|   3 |   2 |
|   4 |   1 |
|   4 |   2 |
|   5 |   1 |
|   5 |   2 |
|   6 |   1 |
|   6 |   2 |
|   7 |   1 |
|   7 |   2 |
|   8 |   1 |
|   8 |   2 |
|   9 |   1 |
|   9 |   2 |
|  10 |   1 |
|  10 |   2 |
+-----+-----+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Vamos a hacer un `LEFT JOIN` de este resultado con `tabla2`, lo cual nos dará `NULL`s para las filas no definidas en `tabla2`:

```
SELECT    t3.id AS idC, t1.id AS idM, t2.id AS idJ
FROM      tabla1 t1
JOIN      tabla3 t3
LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t2.idM = t1.id AND t2.idC = t3.id
ORDER BY  idC, idM;

+-----+-----+------+
| idC | idM | idJ  |
+-----+-----+------+
|   1 |   1 |    1 |
|   1 |   2 |    5 |
|   1 |   3 |    4 |
|   1 |   4 |    3 |
|   1 |   5 |    2 |
|   1 |   6 | NULL |
|   1 |   7 | NULL |
|   1 |   8 | NULL |
|   1 |   9 | NULL |
|   1 |  10 | NULL |
|   2 |   1 |    7 |
|   2 |   2 | NULL |
|   2 |   3 | NULL |
|   2 |   4 |    9 |
|   2 |   5 |    8 |
|   2 |   6 | NULL |
|   2 |   7 | NULL |
|   2 |   8 | NULL |
|   2 |   9 | NULL |
|   2 |  10 | NULL |
+-----+-----+------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Y ya sólo nos queda contar las filas en que `idJ` es `NULL`:

```
SELECT    t3.id AS idC, COUNT(t3.id) AS cnt
FROM      tabla1 t1
JOIN      tabla3 t3
LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t2.idM = t1.id AND t2.idC = t3.id
WHERE     t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY  t3.id
ORDER BY  t3.id;

+-----+-----+
| idC | cnt |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   5 |
|   2 |   7 |
+-----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Otra solución que no requiere un `CROSS JOIN` de dos tablas potencialmente enormes es simplemente contar las filas que sí existen en `tabla2`, y restar el resultado del número total de filas de `tabla1`. Podrías hacerlo con una variable de MySQL, o a posteriori en el código del programa, o con una *subquery* como por ejemplo:

```
SELECT   t2.idC, t1.cnt - COUNT(t2.idC)
FROM     tabla2 t2
JOIN     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tabla1) t1
GROUP BY t2.idC, t1.cnt;

+-----+------------------------+
| idC | t1.cnt - COUNT(t2.idC) |
+-----+------------------------+
|   1 |                      5 |
|   2 |                      7 |
+-----+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Si hiciéramos la operación recíproca para obtener la cuenta correspondiente a cada idM con este query:

```
SELECT   t2.idM, COUNT(t2.idM) AS CNT, t3.cnt - COUNT(t2.idM) AS NCNT
FROM     tabla2 t2
JOIN     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tabla3) t3
GROUP BY t2.idM, t3.cnt;

+-----+-----+------+
| idM | CNT | NCNT |
+-----+-----+------+
|   1 |   2 |    0 |
|   2 |   1 |    1 |
|   3 |   1 |    1 |
|   4 |   2 |    0 |
|   5 |   2 |    0 |
+-----+-----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Para obtener las filas de los valores de `idM` que no aparecen en este último resultado (porque no aparecen en la `tabla2`) tendrías que hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con `tabla1`:

```
SELECT   t1.id AS idM,
         IFNULL(t2.cnt, 0) AS CNT,
         t3.cnt - IFNULL(t2.cnt, 0) AS NCNT
FROM     tabla1 t1
JOIN     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tabla3) t3
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idM, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `tabla2`
    GROUP BY idM
) t2 ON t2.idM = t1.id

+-----+-----+------+
| idM | CNT | NCNT |
+-----+-----+------+
|   1 |   2 |    0 |
|   2 |   1 |    1 |
|   3 |   1 |    1 |
|   4 |   2 |    0 |
|   5 |   2 |    0 |
|   6 |   0 |    2 |
|   7 |   0 |    2 |
|   8 |   0 |    2 |
|   9 |   0 |    2 |
|  10 |   0 |    2 |
+-----+-----+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta porque necesitaría ahora  contar en una columna CNT los registros existentes para cada idM y en una columna NCNT los registros no existentes para cada idM. Gracias.

Comment: @Barnyard He ampliado mi respuesta.

Comment: Excelente respueta, ¡muchas gracias! ¿Cómo podría añadir a continuación más columnas de la tabla3 para que siguieran agrupándose por idM? He intentado añadirlas al SELECT pero se repite el número total y no se agrupan

Comment: ¿A la última tabla? No lo veo posible. Cada fila del resultado contiene la información de (en este caso) dos filas diferentes de `tabla3`. Sólo podrías añadir columnas que tomaran el mismo valor para todas las filas de la `tabla3`. A lo mejor te estás refiriendo a otra cosa.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para aclararlo un poco mejor. Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo la última parte, lo siento.